# Concurrent rows appending in Google Sheets API v4

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

We are using **Google Sheets API v4** for getting and appending rows in a sheet. There is an issue when several requests for rows appending are sent simultaneously, e.g. 4 concurrent requests. Sometimes such requests are intersected and some of the appended rows are overwritten by another requests. For instance if each request has only 1 row for append and 4 such requests are sent at the same moment, only 3 rows are created. This issue doesn't appear in case of sequential requests. Is it known issue? Is there any workaround how we can achieve that rows are not overwritten by concurrent append requests?

For sending an append request we are using batch update request endpoint:
`POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate`

The body of batch update request has "appendCells" property with appropriate append cells request data:

1. "sheetId": appropriate sheet ID;
2. "rows": only one row;
3. "fields": "*"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using the [values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) API with [InsertDataOption.INSERT_ROWS](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#InsertDataOption).  Each request should go to its own new row.

Comment: I tried to use `values.append` request, however there is some challenges. For instance if the first column doesn't contain any values and the `values.append` request is sent with `A1:D1` range, it starts to insert items from the second column (`B`). But if the first column has only one infilled cell, it starts to insert items from the first column (`A`).

Comment: Can you expand on that second point?  We know the first one and have ideas for exposing different modes that would let you insert starting at a different column, but the second one sounds like a bug if it's overwriting data.

Comment: Regarding the second point (if the first column has only one infilled cell, it starts to insert items from the first column (`A`)): it's not overwriting data. The behavior is different if column `A` has any infilled cell or not for the same A1 query. E.g. if query is `A1:D1` and there are 4 cell values in `values.append` request the insert operation actually depends whether column `A` has any (even on different row) infilled cell or not. It really confuses because there is no possibility to find out if the column `A` contains any infilled cells without downloading those to the client.

Comment: P.S. If the query was `A1:A1`, it would insert new row as the first row starting from the first column (`A`) independently whether column `A` has infilled cells or not.

Comment: Ah, I see you.  You're basically just describing the "table detection".  The idea of append is that it tries to append rows after a table, and it uses the the input range to find a table.  If there's no data in a particular column, it doesn't think there's a table there.  https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values#appending_values explains this pretty well.

But, your point about not always wanting the behavior is well taken, and we're looking at ways of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try google apps script Lock Service.

```
function appendRow_(row) {
  // The try / catch statement can be uncommented

  //try {
    var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
    lock.waitLock(10000);

    Do something

    // Post form results with empty responses in order of item index
    s.appendRow(row);
    lock.releaseLock();
  //} 

  //catch (error) { 
     //Insert your own error handling
     //Logger.log(error);
  //}

  //finally { 
    //lock.releaseLock();
  //}
}
```

Comment: I find this slows down the whole API though any full proof way to reserve a row?

Comment: `LockService` is exclusive to Apps Script, while OP is about using the Sheets REST API (i.e. in a 3rd party client that is incapable of running Apps Script code). I'm not sure this answer is relevant to the particulars of the question.

Comment: `flush` of Apps Script also nice to use, which sadly missing in HTTP API for Sheets